# Return empty list for albums without photos

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j database with Albums that contain a list of Photos. Each Photo in turn has a list of Thumbnails. I wrote a query to give me every album including all of its photos (including their thumbnails):

```
MATCH (a:Album)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(p:Photo)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)<-[to:THUMBNAIL_OF]-(t:Thumbnail)
WITH a,p,{uri: t.uri, size: to.size} as thumbnails
WITH a,{id: p.id, uri: p.uri, thumbnails: collect(thumbnails)} as photo
RETURN a.id as albumId, a.name as albumName, collect(photo) as photos
```

The result of this query looks like this:

```
╒══════════════════════════════════╤═════════════╤═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"albumId"                         │"albumName"  │"photos"                                                         │
╞══════════════════════════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"41dmzLK7bCP3Tbm7aVtXH-61LVgJmW57"│"Summer 2019"│[{"id":null,"thumbnails":[{"size":null,"uri":null}],"uri":null}] │
├──────────────────────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"sM4hwUEAfdeQNktoGRRSW4POrugUldyF"│"New Album"  │[{"id":"VO5ixGVygrZ5Z9-H903bJ0XDY6gEbr4s","thumbnails":[{"size":"│
│                                  │             │LARGE","uri":"YVZ9Cz4P2yBPPtpadAmA3yt1"},{"size":"MEDIUM","uri":"│
│                                  │             │X4TADPTbKe2CTY832TVeEdHk"},{"size":"SMALL","uri":"hyy34CeUB36HvxU│
│                                  │             │1YDVE7aTV"},{"size":"TINY","uri":"7h9ADu1Xbm1YDuBBTEKVKaCA"}],"ur│
│                                  │             │i":"xHpxm7zpe1U4v6gTEAm3kdcm"}]                                  │
└──────────────────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The album "Summer 2019" does not contain any photos and I would like the photos to be an empty list instead of the current value with everything set to null. I thought the optional match would help in this case but apparently it doesn't. I guess this is because I create custom structs in my query.

How can I change my query to achieve that?

Comment: Use coalesce to define default value when null is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) to do the equivalent of `OPTIONAL MATCH` and to automatically provide an empty list when there are no matches:

```
MATCH (a:Album)
RETURN a.id AS albumId, a.name AS albumName,
  [(a)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(p:Photo) |
    {id: p.id, uri: p.uri, thumbnails:
      [(p)<-[to:THUMBNAIL_OF]-(t:Thumbnail) | {uri: t.uri, size: to.size}]
    }
  ] AS photos
```

*By the way, shouldn't the `size` property be on `Thumbnail` node? Might allow some other queries to be more efficient.*

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Putting `size` on the relationship was just following my gut feeling. Might put it on the node as well but I need to read up on query efficiency first.

Comment: If you put `size` on the relationship, then whenever you need the size you would be forced to expend the overhead to get the relationship even though you may already have the `Thumbnail` node. And what if you have multiple relationships to the same thumbnail -- would you be putting the same size in all of them? Plus it makes your queries more complex to write and read. In general, put properties where they "naturally" belong. Since a thumbnail has a fixed size -- and the size has nothing to do with any relationships it might or might not have --you should put the size in the thumbnail.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for clarifying!